# If I clone a private repo (that I have access to) from Company A into company B will company B have access to that cloned repo

Tags: github, repo, cloning

I was given access to a private repo from company A and would like to clone this repo such that everyone in company B can view the code as well. However company B does not have access to the private repo, only me. Is this possible? Thank you!

Thank you for your help!